# In the Hamming code, how many control bits are needed to be able to correct an error in 15-bits transmited

Tags: error-correcting-codes, hamming-code

i don't know if right answer is 4 or 5 !
what did you understand from this question if it was a QCM ?
thanks

Comment: What does QCM stand for?

Comment: IT MEANS CMQ ,multiple choises question

Comment: i found it is 5 ,but my teacher insits that it is 4 !

Answer (score 0):

Since Hamming codes have minimum distance 3, you can always correct a single error. What you are really asking is what is the rate of the Hamming code whose block length is 15 bits. This is information that is readily available from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code), according to which for every $r$ there is a Hamming code with block length $2^r-1$ and message length $2^r-r-1$ (which leaves $r$ control bits). Now it remains to find the value of $r$.

Comment: i don't know if the right answer is 4 or 5 ? 
which one is correct plz

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to figure that out on your own. The goal of the site is not for us to solve your homework, but to help you understand the material enough so that you can solve it yourself.

Comment: i did ,i found out it is 5 ,but my teacher said its 4 !!!